# Adicionar transição ao código

Tags: javascript

Eu estou usando esse código para mostrar e esconder divs conforme o clique. Porém ele não apresenta nenhuma transição e parece muito "seco" ao clicar. Não sei muito bem mexer em Javascript, então estou tendo problemas.

```js
function mostra(theId){
var theArray= new Array('thms', 'pgs');
w=document.getElementById(theId)
    if(w.style.display=="block"){w.style.display='none';}else{ 

        for(i=0; i<theArray.length; i++){
          if(theArray[i] == theId){
            w.style.display='block';
          }else{
            document.getElementById(theArray[i]).style.display='none';
            }
        }
    }

}
```

```css
#thms, #pgs{margin-top: 40px;}
.t, .p{cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
                <a onclick="mostra('thms')" class="t";>themes</a>
                <a onclick="mostra('pgs');" class="p">pages</a>
             </div>
             
             <div id="thms" style="display:none;">
                 <ul>
                     <li><a href="/">all themes</a></li>
                     <li><a href="/">one column</a></li>
                     <li><a href="/">+two columns</a></li>
                     <li><a href="/">minimalist</a></li>
                     <li><a href="/">full sidebar</a></li>
                     <li><a href="/">infinite scroll</a></li>
                     <li><a href="/">load more</a></li>
                     <li><a href="/">250px</a></li>
                     <li><a href="/">400px</a></li>
                     <li><a href="/">500px</a></li>
                     <li><a href="/">540px</a></li>
                     <li><a href="/">multi post sizes</a></li>
                 </ul>
             </div>
             
             <div id="pgs" style="display:none;">
                 <ul>
                     <li><a href="/">all pages</a></li>
                     <li><a href="/">minimalist</a></li>
                     <li><a href="/">grid</a></li>
                     <li><a href="/">portifolio</a></li>
                     <li><a href="/">blogroll</a></li>
                     <li><a href="/">about</a></li>
                     <li><a href="/">all in one</a></li>
                     <li><a href="/">tags pages</a></li>
                 </ul>
             </div>
```

Comment: jQuery é bom para fazer essas coisas.

Comment: Existe uma lib muito legal e fácil de mexer que talvez facilitaria sua vida para fazer esse tipo de trabalho se chama anime.js https://animejs.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como foi comentado, você pode utilizar o Jquery para isso, aqui tem um pequeno exemplo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Animação com Jquery</title>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
       #thms, #pgs{margin-top: 40px;}
   .t, .p{cursor: pointer;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  
 
 <div class="menu">
  <a id="btn_thms" class="t";>themes</a>
        <a id="btn_pgs" class="p">pages</a>
 </div>
 
 <div id="thms" style="display:none;">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="/">all themes</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">one column</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">+two columns</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">minimalist</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">full sidebar</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">infinite scroll</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">load more</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">250px</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">400px</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">500px</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">540px</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">multi post sizes</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
             
  <div id="pgs" style="display:none;">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="/">all pages</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">minimalist</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">grid</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">portifolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">blogroll</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">about</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">all in one</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">tags pages</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  
</body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
       
   $('#btn_thms').click(function () {
     $('#pgs').hide(); 
     $('#thms').show( "slow"); 
     $("#thms").animate({height: '400px', opacity: '0.4'},700);
     $("#thms").animate({width: '500px', opacity: '1'}, 1000);
        });
  
  $('#btn_pgs').click(function () {
            $('#thms').hide(); 
   $('#pgs').show('slow'); 
            $("#pgs").animate({left: '100px'}, "slow");
   $("#pgs").animate({fontSize: '3em'}, "slow");
        });
  
  
    });
 
 
</script>
</html>
```

Você pode dar uma olhada no efeito animate, aqui tem alguns tutoriais com outros exemplos:

http://www.eduardocs.com/artigos/tutorial-com-jquery-animate.html
https://spigandoeaprendendo.wordpress.com/2014/03/05/jquery-animacoes-customizadas-com-o-metodo-animate/
http://www.robsonmoulin.com.br/artigos/front-end/site-ancora-simples-com-efeito-animate-do-jquery/

Comment: Obrigada! Fiz algumas alterações nas animações e juntei com o filter Isotope e ficou do jeito que eu queria.